# Fetch a specific branch using git

Tags: git, github

I want to download source code from the [master-next branch](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/tree/master-next) using git as described in the [Xilinx wiki](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Fetch+Sources).

I tried this:

```
#git clone git://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/tree/master-next.git

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Hannan/master-next/.git/
fatal: remote error:
Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/tree/master-next is not a valid repository name
Email support@github.com for help
```

Even this failed:

```
# git clone git://github.com/Xilinx/tree/master-next/u-boot-xlnx.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Hannan/u-boot-xlnx/.git/
fatal: remote error:
Xilinx/tree/master-next/u-boot-xlnx is not a valid repository name
Email support@github.com for help
```

The command that works is:

```
 git clone git://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git
```

But how do I know that this will indeed fetch the [master-next branch](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/tree/master-next) and not the [master branch](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/tree/master)? How do I correctly fetch a specific branch using git?

I am using RHEL 6, accessed via PuTTY.

Answer (score 16):

Like the error message tells you, `git clone` expects a git repository. You can't "add" the name of a branch in the path like that. See [branches in git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching).

You can clone a single branch (and it's history) :
`git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch`

See `git help clone`.

But the clone command you ran gave you a copy of the whole repository, you can see the existing branches with `git branch` and more details about them with `git show-branch`.

Switch to the branch you want with `git checkout branch-name`.

The first chapters of the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book (available online) give more details on the basic commands.

Comment: "clone command you ran gave you a copy of the whole repository".whole repository means both branches merged ?

Comment: No they are not merged. A branch in git is not a copy of the whole directory, as [explained here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is).

Comment: What I did is this:  "git clone -b master-next https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git" is this not correct ?

Comment: You didn't need clone anymore. The command you showed in your question gave you the repository with all the branches. But this is correct too. It's equivalent to doing `git checkout master-next` after cloning.

Answer (score 13):

This command should work:

```
$ git fetch origin [branch]
```

The above command only fetches metadata from remote repository, it doesn't merge sources.

If you want fetch and merge the sources it should be:

```
$ git pull origin [branch]
```

Be careful with the branch where you are executing merge command. That branch will be where the sources are merged.

#**UPDATE**# grammatical checking/re-writing

Comment: Your answer is technically correct but I think it might benefit from some grammatical checking/re-writing.

Comment: this works nicely thx

Answer (score 4):

git repositories contain all branches (but compressed and only differences hence rarely a size issue).

Therefore, you can clone the entire project as you have done successfully.  This is a standard way to get a repository, even if you are only interest in one branch.

The .git structure will then include *all* the branches done on that repository.

To use a specific branch do `git checkout [branch_name]`
If the branch exists the files will be made available locally (as just that, the current files in the project directories).

`git status` will then show which branch is the current branch, for example:

According to Leiaz one can clone a specific branch.  In practice I've never done this or seen others use it.  On further research, I see it is relatively new, added in git 1.7.10 (April 2012): 'git clone learned --single-branch' option to limit cloning to a single branch (surprise!); tags that do not point into the history of the branch are not fetched.
For example:

```
git clone -b master-next --single-branch git://github.com/Xilinx/
```

[image]
Here, for my "linker" application I am checking out branch `v3.0.10`

Comment: I've never done it either, I remembered seeing the option. I guess it's rarely used as extra branches are "cheap" in size.